# Github bootstrap UI? Or github-like UI template

Tags: layout, user-interface, github, twitter-bootstrap

I really appreciate Github's website look & feel and I would like to "clone" it on a admin tool I'm developing right now.

Does anyone knows if there's a Github Bootstrakp (just like Twitter bootstrap) or something similar? Perhaps a Github-like UI admin template ...

I found their Style Guide page (https://github.com/styleguide/) but wasn't able to get the css and javascript source codes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at this https://styleguide.github.com/primer/getting_started/

Answer (score 5):

Github's ui is not open source as far as I know, however there is a FOSS clone called gitlabhq:

http://gitlabhq.com/

And the source is available on github:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq

Comment: I think this is about the UI part, not cloning the git-hosting functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I know. GitLab's ui is pretty similar to github's (or at least was at time of writing), but is also open source.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/primer/primer described as

> CSS toolkit that powers GitHub's front-end design. It's purposefully limited to common components to provide our developers with the most flexibility, and to keep GitHub uniquely GitHubby. It's built with SCSS and available via NPM, so it's easy to include all or part of it within your own project.